# Java 7 Watch Service cannot detect events properly

Tags: java, watchservice, nio2

I have created a watch service java application using nio2's WatchService for a Linux server whereby I have it watching some directories in a mounted NAS drive. The files will arrive by NFS, MQ or SFTP.

I have read in other places stating that the WatchService will not be able to work on remote drives however it seems that it does work when I test it.

My tests are a mix of copying or 'touching' new files into the watched directory as the user that I've used to run the java service.

The problem:
My WatchService is not detecting ANY events in those specific directories during live deployment. Upon further inspection, the files are owned by a different user/group than the one used to execute my java program.

As such I have performed a test whereby I had created a new user from a new group and then touched/copied into the directory and it works! The permissions of ALL the files are at least read for EVERYONE. (and even testing with no read for everyone, my program will at least log the CREATE_EVENT regardless)

I'm not able to procure access for the users that were used for NFS/MQ/SFTP to test out this problem. So I'm looking for some help or at least clarity on the issue that I'm facing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java watch service often cannot detect events on a remote mounted file system.   This is what the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) says:

> If a watched file is not located on a local storage device then it is implementation specific if changes to the file can be detected. In particular, it is not required that changes to files carried out on remote systems be detected.

Why?  Because the underlying OS functionality that Java is using to implement the watch service can't do this either<sup>1</sup>.

Why?  Because the remote file system protocols don't support this.   Certainly NFS doesn't.  And neither does [SMB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577788/monitor-remote-shared-folder-windows-smb-using-watchservice).

Why?  Because it wouldn't be reliable, it wouldn't be efficient, and it wouldn't scale!

If you really need to implement file watching for remote file systems, you will need to do it on the system where the files actually reside.

---

<sup>1 - It is a bad idea to specify behavior that cannot be implemented!</sup>

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. I agree with you. It was just the fact that it could work in most of my test cases even though many places said outright that it would never work in any case. Also, this was the neatest implementation I could use since it wouldn't poll. I've moved on now to use Apache Commons IO to listen to the folders

Comment: The probable reason your tests were working is that the watch service was running on the same machine that was changing the files.

Comment: I have a less complex problem. I am running a watcher service on linux machine, monitoring the folders on that same server. But the watcher is only picking up files when I manually push the documents in those folders (through WinSCP/SSH). The actual scenario is when the files come from Scanner and Fax machines, and sit in these folders. In this case, the watcher service is not picking up files. Any idea what can be the issue ? I already checked the permissions on the incoming file. It is with the root user only, the same user with which my watcher service is running.

Comment: I resolved with the help of this code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919086/java-watch-service-not-working-for-remote-files-mounted-in-the-local-server?rq=1

Comment: By the way, with NFS the watch service works (but with SMB it doesn't).